# About ToTensorV2() about albumentations

Tags: artificial-intelligence, transform, albumentations

I am using ToTensorV2() to transform the data, but I asked ChatGPT if this function can scale the data to 0 - 1, and it answered yes. However, when I use cv2.imread() to read an image and pass the image to the transform, the data doesn't scale. Do I have an error somewhere, or do I need to scale to 0 - 1 manually?

transform = A.Compose([A.HorizontalFlip(p=1), ToTensorV2()])